# Вызов метода 1 класса из 2 класса, не зная тип 1 класса

Tags: c#

Сразу прошу прощение за формулировку в заголовке. Попробую объяснить на примере:

1. Есть тестовый класс `Test`

В нем есть 2 метода:

```
public static void Start()
{
    Timer.TimerStart<string>(string s); //вызываем метод из 2 класса
}

public static void Finish(string s)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

2. У нас есть 2 класс `Timer`

В нем есть статический метод `TimerStart<T>(T s)`

```
public static TimerStart<T>(T s)
{
    //вызываем метод из класса <x> с названием <y> с параметром <T>;
    //x.y(s);

    // В конкретном примере мы должны вызвать
    Main.Finish(s);
}
```

Что нужно реализовать:

1. Вызываем метод `Start()` из 1 класса.
2. В нем мы должны запустить статический метод TimerStart из 2 класса и передать ему в качестве параметра стринговую строку. `Timer.TimerStart(string s)`
3. В метода `TimerStart` мы должны вызвать метод `Finish(string s)` из первого класса.

Возможно ли это сделать в C# при условии, что функция во 2 классе не обязательно должна вызывать функцию именно 1 класса? Это могут быть функции и других классов.

Фактически мне нужно из 1 класса передать ссылку на класс и функцию (с параметрами) во 2 класс. Пробовал реализовать это с помощью делегатов, но из-за малого опыта ничего не выходит.

Comment: `public static void Start();` лишние `;` - вы уверены, что этот код компилируется? Отредактируйте вопрос так, чтобы ошибки в коде не бросались в глаза. Код должен компилироваться. Если у вас не получается это сделать, укажите ошибку компилятора, которую вы не можете побороть.

Comment: Окей, мы не знаем точно какой класс будет. А можем знать, например, что класс реализовывает интерфейс `IRunnable { void OnStart(); void OnFinish() }`?

Comment: aepot, Вопрос в реализации, я мог вообще не писать код, а оформить все в словесной форме. Вы уверены что ваша придирка имеет место быть? Может у Вас не хватает знаний, чтобы ответить на мой вопрос, но ответить что-то хочется?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test.Start();
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        Action action = () => Finish("Some string");
        Timer.TimerStart(action);
    }

    public static void Finish(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}

public class Timer
{
    public static void TimerStart(Action action)
    {
        action();
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за быстрый ответ! Именно это и нужно! Боялся, что неправильно понимаю смысл использования делегатов, но нет, работает именно так! Пойду читать про делегаты более подробно...